# How do you overcome recursion limits when using DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, precision-and-accuracy

I have the following program to solve for the neutron to baryon ratio during BBN.  I've replaced many of the derived values with constants in order to focus on the problem:

```
ClearAll[rate, hubble, equation, initialConditions, fraction]
rate[x_] := (0.28*(12 + 6*x + x^2))/x^5
hubble[x_] := 1.73*^-13/Sqrt[x]
equation := Derivative[1][fraction][x] == (rate[x]/(x*hubble[x]))*((1 - fraction[x])/E^x - fraction[x]); 
initialConditions := fraction[0.12] == 0.46
fraction[x_] = fraction[x] /. NDSolve[{equation, initialConditions}, fraction[x], {x, 0.3, 100}]
LogLogPlot[2*fraction[x], {x, 0.65, 65}]
```

In the domain where $x\approx1$, this ODE goes berserk with these error messages:

`NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 0.12, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.`

When I try to plot the ODE solution, I get:

`$IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.`

Here is an image of the progress of the ODE solution as a function of **hubble**.  I would expect the solution to the ODE to have the shape of the fifth plot in this series as **hubble** approaches zero.

[image]

I've no idea what this means or how to fix it.  It appears to be an issue with precision.  How can I fix this?  My target is to get this section of code working when $hubble=10^{-13}$.

Comment: Can you run to just before the problem and then plot the solution. Sounds like you have hit a singularity. Look to see if the solution is going off to infinity.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are asking.  The problem occurs during the evaluation of the ODE.  I've got nothing to plot before I have the solution to the ODE.

Comment: Try reducing the upper limit of the solution range to about 0.12 and plot the solution to find the behaviour as it approaches 0.12

Comment: The function **fraction** approaches 0.5 as x goes to zero.

Comment: MMA 12.1 If I run your code, I get a nice solution, no error. Question: is `hubble[x_] := 10^(-4)`o.k.?

Comment: The ODE has a symbolic solution involving a numerical integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computation in the question can be performed by using a higher `WorkingPrecison`, which in turn requires rationalizing all decimals and employing the option, `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`, to avoid the inexplicable NDSolveValue::nderr (Error test failure).

```
rate[x_] := Rationalize[(0.28*(12 + 6*x + x^2))/x^5, 0]
hubble[x_] := Rationalize[1.73*^-13/Sqrt[x], 0]
equation := Derivative[1][fraction][x] == (rate[x]/(x*hubble[x]))*
    ((1 - fraction[x])/E^x - fraction[x]);
initialConditions := fraction[12/100] == 46/100
sn = NDSolveValue[{equation, initialConditions}, fraction[x], {x, 12/100, 100}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 45, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
LogLogPlot[2*sn, {x, 0.65, 65}, PlotRange -> {.8 10^-3, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Note that `WorkingPrecision -> 30` may appear to give a reasonable plot, but produces inaccurate results when integrating over `{x, 12/100, 3/10}`, which `NDSolve` must do to apply the boundary condition.  Note also that `fraction[x]` has an `Accuracy` of only about `-15`, and improving it by using `WorkingPrecision -> 60` is interminably slow.

Comment: what purpose does using fractions like $\frac{12}{100}$ instead of real numbers serve?  Those constants I placed in the original post (in order to simplify the issue) are actually the results of other, non-trivial functions.  Do I have to 'rationalize' them as well?

Comment: @Quarkly,  `NDSolve` with `WorkingPrecision` set to a larger value than `$MachinePrecision`  refuses to run, if the the precisions of numbers given to `NDSolve` are not at least as large as the value of   `WorkingPrecision`.  I use `Rationalize`, because it is easy and gives infinite precision.  By the way, I may have a different approach, but I need to think about it a bit.

Comment: This looks very promising.  Thank you for the insight into 'Rationalize'.  I had tried it, but didn't understand fully how it worked, so I didn't follow it through.

Answer (score 2):

Here a version whithout multiple redefinitions of `fraction[]`:

```
rate[x_] := ( 28/100*(12 + 6*x + x^2))/x^5
hubble[x_] := hub
equation :=Derivative[1][fraction][
x] == (rate[x]/(x*hubble[x]))*((1 - fraction[x])/E^x - fraction[x]);
```

initialConditions := fraction[0.12] == 46/100

```
 fractionN =ParametricNDSolveValue[{equation, initialConditions}, fraction , {x, 0.3, 100}, hub, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching",WorkingPrecision -> 25]

 LogLogPlot[Table[2*fractionN[hub][x], {hub, Table[10^-n, {n, 1, 6}]}] //Evaluate, {x, 0.3, 100}, PlotLegends -> N[Table[10^-n, {n, 1, 6}]]]//Quiet
```

[image]

Comment: Does the solution for $hubble=10^{-6}$ look at all physical?  I appreciate the effort, but that looks to me like a function on the verge of a nervous breakdown.

Comment: Yes , see  my modified answer(`WorkingPrecision->25` )

Comment: Sorry, but after researching the ParametricNDSolveValue function, this doesn't do what I need it to do.  While the function **hubble** returns a value on the order of $10^{-13}$, the function, as well as the **rate** function are both dependent on x and can't be solved outside of the ODE.  Trying to force this answer back into NDSolve just brings me back to the original problem.

Comment: @Quarkly Your proposed edit in the review queue is hard to read (not your fault, it's just formatted in a narrow column). It looked like you were suggesting a change to one line of code in effect.  You could do that in a comment, instead of adding such a long edit to this post.  (Or I misread it, which is the reason for my first remark.)

Comment: My intension was to make this easy to verify my changes.  If you take the entire chunk of code that I posted and paste it into MMa, you'll see the effect I'm addressing.  I figured that was easier than trying to give instructions on how to edit the first chunk of code that Ulrich posted.

Comment: Well, Ulrich can decide. He can review the edit.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry I had trouble to review the edit. Now my modified answer works and  gives the idea, how to use `WorkingPrecision` to answer the question in principle. Case `10^-13` needs more effort and is left to the OP.

Comment: @Quarkly My answer leaves `rate[x]` unchanged. Only `hubble[x] ` is set to a constant value `hub` , as you asked for before modifying your question!